# Convert escaped unicode character to unicode notation

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have a DB2 LUW table with escaped unicode characters in it.
I want to convert this to a real unicode string.

```
$ db2 "select loc_longtext from fh01tq07 where loc_longtext like '%\\u%'"

LOC_LONGTEXT
------------
S\u00e4ule
```

After long time try and error I'm at this point:

```
$ db2 "select loc_longtext, xmlquery('fn:replace(\$LOC_LONGTEXT,''\\\u([0-9a-f]{1,4})'',''&#x\$1;'')') from fh01tq07 where loc_longtext like '%\\u%'"

SQL16002N  An XQuery expression has an unexpected token "&#x" following "]{1,4})','". Expected tokens may include: "&lt;". Error QName=err:XPST0003.  SQLSTATE=10505
```

But fn:normalize-unicode requests this type of escaped unicode format.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please tag whether you are trying to use `LUW` or `ZOS` flavor of DB2, because `fn:replace` has no copy from input `$1` in ZOS

Comment: it's db2-luw on aix

Comment: I think you need double quotes for string literals in the XQuery text, like `\"&#x\$1;\"`

Comment: Single or double quotes shouldn't matter for XQuery text since XML allows both. However, in cases like this I first try to use a SQL editor and avoid the command line to reduce some string escaping. Do you mean "\$1" or just "$1"?

Comment: Nope, same result...

Comment: The problem is not the replace/regex but the & charactor. When I use an other char like ? it is working.